# GROUP by in the query - What I'm doing wrong with it?

Tags: mysql, group-by

SQLFiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ade6a

It's been 2 days that I'm trying to figure out this issue. In the database that I'm working on, they didn't use relations between tables. So it makes it even harder to fix something. I read all topic related with "GROUP BY" but they only worked up to a point.

My example tables.

**Messages** (actually I should have named as Conversation to not to mixup)

```
Id   No      s_id     r_id   adddate
----------------------------------------
1            7        6     2015-10-30 01:51:17     
2           15        6     2015-11-19 18:06:47
3           16        15    2015-11-22 19:28:01
4           7         15    2015-11-22 19:58:33
5           16        7     2015-11-22 20:36:36
```

**Message_items**

```
   id  m_id u_id  message               ip             addate     
     ----- -------------------------------------------------------------
    30  2   15  admin to user attempt2  127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 18:28:21
    31  2   6   user6 to admin attempt  127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 18:59:45 
    32  2   15  admin to user attempt3  127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 19:05:13

    33  3   16  user16 to admin attmp1  127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 19:28:01
    34  3   15  admin to user16 reply1  127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 19:30:01
    35  3   16  user16 to admin attempt2 127.0.0.1  2015-11-22 19:32:36

    36  4   7   user7 to admin attemp1  127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 19:59:52
    38  4   7   user7 to admin attempt2 127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 21:19:18
    39  4   7   user7 to admin attempt3 127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 21:20:19

   37   5   16  user16 to user7 attmpt1 127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 20:36:36
   40   5   7  user7  to user16 reply1 127.0.0.1   2015-11-22 20:45:12
```

m_id stands for the id in messages table. 
s_id sender, r_id receiver, u_id user.

At first I was using this **query:** I'm supposing id's are 16 now.

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT m.id, m.s_id, m.r_id, i.id as i_id, i.u_id, i.m_id, i.adddate, i.message 
    FROM messages as m, 
    messages_items as i, 
    users as u 
    WHERE (m.s_id=16 or m.r_id=16) 
    and i.m_id=m.id 
    and u.id=i.u_id  
    ORDER BY i.id DESC

) as tmp GROUP BY m_id ORDER BY i_id DESC
```

**Output:** 
Im not writing attribute "no" since its too long.

```
 id | no | s_id |r_id|i_id|u_id| m_id|    adddate         |  message     

 5 |      | 16  | 7  | 37 | 16 | 5   | 2015-11-22 20:36:36| user16 to user7 attempt1
 3 |      | 16  | 15 |  33| 16 | 3   | 2015-11-22 19:28:01| user16 to admin attempt1
```

**What I need:**  As it can be seen in the Message_items there are 2 more message attempts after first one. I want the last one to be group with.

**Desired Output:**

```
 id | no | s_id |r_id|i_id|u_id| m_id|    adddate         |  message     

 5 |      | 7  | 16  | 40 | 7  | 5    | 2015-11-22 20:45:12| user7 to user16 reply1
 3 |      | 16  | 15 | 35 | 16 | 3   | 2015-11-22 19:32:36| user16 to admin attempt2
```

**What I have tried?**

1.I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages_items   
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages_items.m_id = messages.id   
WHERE messages_items.adddate=(SELECT MAX(adddate) FROM messages_items)
```

This query is close to what I want but it only gives one result with this query. 
Output:

```
id  m_id  u_id  id  s_id r_id        adddate           adddate   
39  4      7     4   7    15  2015-11-22 21:20:19 2015-11-22 19:58:33
       message
user7 to admin attempt3
```

This gives the latest message I think. I tried it with GROUP BY but it didnt work. It doesnt show other groups.

2. **Attempt**

This query also gives the results but I need fetch information from other table as well. For example fetching I need to fetch **No**, **s_id** and **r_id** from messages table.

```
SELECT m_id, adddate, message,   
    i.id as i_id, i.u_id 
FROM messages_items as i
WHERE adddate=(  
    SELECT MAX(adddate)   
    FROM messages_items   
    WHERE m_id = i.m_id 
)GROUP BY m_id
```

I'm looking forward for your suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Edit: To simplify problem; I need to GROUP BY message items with closest date first. 
So that when I open messages section, the latest message item will appear in the preview. In the first query that I've written,it doesnt GROUP them in this order.

Second Edit:  if you are trying to achive my aim, I have also added  (m.r_id=16 OR m.s_id=16) to last WHERE clause to the solution of @fancyPants

Comment: Try `SELECT *, MAX(adddate) FROM messages_items   
LEFT JOIN messages   
ON messages_items.m_id = messages.id   
GROUP BY id`

Comment: Sorry, the `id` is suppose to be `m_id`

Comment: for the format a the question I gave you an upvote, certainly an example for new users

Comment: The format of your question if very good, but I'm having trouble understanding the output you want, could you explain it without the result? Already created a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ade6a for testing

Comment: @frz3993 Thanks for your answer. since in this way it gives 'adddate' in field list is ambiguos error, I tried this SELECT *, MAX(i.adddate) FROM messages_items as i LEFT JOIN messages as m ON i.m_id = m.id GROUP BY i.m_id which gives the max dates true but the messages which doesnt belongs to those dates.

Comment: @davejal Thanks. Glad to here that. Im adding further information.

Comment: If i'm correct @fancypants gave you a solution and an explanation, did you try it?

Comment: @davejal yes, it is solved. Thanks for your time and sqlfiddle as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you almost had it in your last query. The `GROUP BY` is not needed here, referencing the outer query from the subquery already does the grouping.

Then you just have to join one more time to messages:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM message_items as i
JOIN messages m ON i.m_id = m.id
WHERE i.addate=(  
    SELECT MAX(adddate)   
    FROM message_items   
    WHERE m_id = i.m_id 
)
```

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE messages
    (`Id` int, `s_id` int, `r_id` varchar(10), `adddate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO messages
    (`Id`, `s_id`, `r_id`, `adddate`)
VALUES
    (1, 7, 6, '2015-10-30 01:51:17'),
    (2, 15, 6, '2015-11-19 18:06:47'),
    (3, 16, 15, '2015-11-22 19:28:01'),
    (4, 7, 15, '2015-11-22 19:58:33'),
    (5, 16, 7, '2015-11-22 20:36:36')
;


CREATE TABLE message_items
    (`id` int, `m_id` int, `u_id` int, `message` varchar(28), `ip` varchar(9), `addate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO message_items
    (`id`, `m_id`, `u_id`, `message`, `ip`, `addate`)
VALUES
    (30, 2, 15, '''admin to user attempt2''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T18:28:21'),
    (31, 2, 6, '''user6 to admin attempt''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T18:59:45'),
    (32, 2, 15, '''admin to user attempt3''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T19:05:13'),
    (33, 3, 16, '''user16 to admin attmp1''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T19:28:01'),
    (34, 3, 15, '''admin to user16 reply1''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T19:30:01'),
    (35, 3, 16, '''user16 to admin attempt2''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T19:32:36'),
    (36, 4, 7, '''user7 to admin attemp1''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T19:59:52'),
    (38, 4, 7, '''user7 to admin attempt2''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T21:19:18'),
    (39, 4, 7, '''user7 to admin attempt3''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T21:20:19'),
    (37, 5, 16, '''user16 to user7 attmpt1''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T20:36:36'),
    (40, 5, 7, '''user7  to user16 reply1''', '127.0.0.1', '2015-11-22T20:45:12')
;
```

the above query produces this result:

```
| id | m_id | u_id |                   message |        ip |                     addate | Id | s_id | r_id |                    adddate |
|----|------|------|---------------------------|-----------|----------------------------|----|------|------|----------------------------|
| 33 |    3 |   16 |  'user16 to admin attmp1' | 127.0.0.1 | November, 22 2015 19:28:01 |  3 |   16 |   15 | November, 22 2015 19:28:01 |
| 37 |    5 |   16 | 'user16 to user7 attmpt1' | 127.0.0.1 | November, 22 2015 20:36:36 |  5 |   16 |    7 | November, 22 2015 20:36:36 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bd82/2/0)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This works exactly in the way I want. You saved my life with a little touch.  Cheers.